# SQL show first unique values according to row then second unique value

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this

Table name: tasks

```
+---------+-------------+-------------
| Name    | taskName    | issueDate  |
+---------+-------------+-------------
| A       | AA          | 4/11/2022  |
| A       | AB          | 4/11/2022  |
| A       | AC          | 4/11/2022  |
| B       | BA          | 3/11/2022  |
| B       | BB          | 3/11/2022  |
| B       | BC          | 3/11/2022  |
| C       | CA          | 2/11/2022  |
| C       | CB          | 2/11/2022  |
+---------+-------------+-------------
```

Resulted table will be like this

```
+---------+-------------+------------
| Name    | taskName    | issueTime |
+---------+-------------+------------
| A       | AA          | 4/11/2022 |
| B       | BA          | 3/11/2022 |
| C       | CA          | 2/11/2022 |
| A       | AB          | 4/11/2022 |
| B       | BB          | 3/11/2022 |
| C       | CB          | 2/11/2022 |
| A       | AC          | 4/11/2022 |
| C       | CB          | 2/11/2022 |
+---------+-------------+-----------|
```

Show the unique name first according to `issueTime` in descending order.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

First give a row number for each 'name' group in the ascending order of issue date and taskname, then sort the result set by the row number.

**Query**

```
select t.name, t.taskname, t.issuedate from(
  select row_number() over(
    partition by name
    order by issuedate, taskname
  ) as rn, *
  from tasks
) as t
order by t.rn, t.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query would be useful for the mentioned scenario:

```
select name, taskname, issuedate from(
select name, taskname, issuedate, row_number() over(partition by name order by issuedate desc) as row_number 
from task)
order by rownum;
```